# convert sqlalchemy query written for sqlite to postgres

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Flask app made using sqlite and now converting to postgres.  I have the following query to gather the daily sales from multiple stores.  Then put the sales into a list to use in a chartjs chart.

```
    daily_chart = (
        db.session.query(Sales, func.sum(Sales.sales).label("total_sales"))
        .filter(Sales.date >= start_week, Sales.date <= end_week)
        .group_by(Sales.date)
        .order_by(Sales.date)
    )
    values1 = []
    for v in daily_chart:
        values1.append(v.total_sales)
```

I get the following error.

```
(psycopg2.errors.GroupingError) column "Sales.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

I tried to use with_entities but don't really know sql and could't find an answer that worked with the func statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `Sales` from the `query` statement.

Comment: I just changed Sales to Sales.date in the query and it worked.

Comment: Yeah that too. Having Sales there I think was trying to bring the id which you can't if you don't group by id.

Comment: In SQL, you can see this behavior, see this DBFIDDLE: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&rdbms2=postgres_14&fiddle=61f0119b624506a484710ffb6960cfd6